# Setting predefined zoom levels

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server, arcmap

I was wondering how to set the predefined zoom levels in the arc gis map.  My ultimate goal is if the user zooms out past level 5 turn off the labels.  Other wise every thing under level 4 show the labels.  I've set the zoom level to 7 and initial load this works correctly.  But when I log the zoom level to the console I get -1 and a description of no predefined zoom levels.  Obviously I'm missing something here but what, wouldnt the log show a zoom level of 7 since that is what is defined for the map?

```
    function init() {        

    esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = WebRoot + "proxy.ashx ";


    map = new esri.Map("mapDiv", {
        basemap: "gray",
        sliderStyle: "large",
        center: [-95.625, 39.243],
        nav: false,
        logo: false,
        zoom: 7
    });//end base map

    //create feature layer
    fl = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(app.regionMap, {
        mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,            
        outFields: ["FIPS"],
        opacity: 0.3,
        visibile: true
    });//ends feature layer

    //add feature layer to map
    map.addLayer(fl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the LODs, or Level of Detail. This is an array provided in the options when you initialise the map, as shown in the [documentation.](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1)

You can pull the LODs from a tiled map layer that you load, as in [this sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/map_switch_layer_on_zoom.html), or define them yourself, eg:

```
_LODS : [
{"level" : 0, "resolution" : 156543.033928, "scale" : 591657527.591555}, 
{"level" : 1, "resolution" : 78271.5169639999, "scale" : 295828763.795777}, 
{"level" : 2, "resolution" : 39135.7584820001, "scale" : 147914381.897889}, 
//...etc
]
```

Comment: yea i did see that but this map isnt a tiled map so was looking for another solution

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think the levels may never be defined *unless* you have a tiled map service loaded...? Ahh, here we are: [linky](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map.html#getlevel), assuming you're using `.getLevel()`

Comment: yea using get level they are never defined but I needed to access the level in the update-end method then i can define maxLevel and minLevel and do what ever I needed.  Took me a whole day to figure that out.  Had to come back to it